# $xyz = \frac{7}{16}\left(\frac{2x - y - z}{3}\right)^3$ in nonvanishing integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

From research completely unrelated to Number Theory I stumbled onto the following equation:

$$
xyz = \frac{7}{16}\left(\frac{2x - y - z}{3}\right)^3
$$

for $x, y, z$ integers, $x,y,z \neq 0$. Are there nonvanishing integers that satisfy it (there are many solutions if one of them is zero)?

Comment: Minor comment: if you put $x=-w/2$ then the equation becomes $wyz=7((w+y+z)/6)^3$, which looks a bit nicer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  This can be verified via the following Magma code, which can be used on the [free Magma online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc):

```
P<x,y,z>:=ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(),2);
C:=Curve(P,x*y*z-7/16*((2*x-y-z)/3)^3);
E:=EllipticCurve(C);
MordellWeilGroup(E);
```

which outputs

```
Abelian Group isomorphic to Z/3
Defined on 1 generator
Relations:
    3*$.1 = 0
```

This shows that, when the given equation is viewed as a curve in $\mathbf{P}^2$, it has exactly three rational points.
One can use Magma to automatically compute these three points, or just observe that there are obviously three rational points with $xyz=0$.

Comment: I suppose a proof "by hand" is too much to ask for?

Comment: You can write the equation in Weierstrass form and use the point of order 3 to do a 3-descent. Since there are only three bad primes (2,3,7) this seems doable. (This works only if there are no elements of order 3 in the Tate-Shafarevich group).

Comment: probably working in Sage will give you more info. It can identify the curve in certain database, etc...

Comment: Thanks! That's fine enough by me although I agree that a proof by hand would be also nice.

Comment: Michael, in case you noticed my earlier comments, I was able to put a little subset of my package in the Magma online calculator and get correct genera and spinor genera for two well-known positive ternary quadratic forms. This is great. They come out as symmetric (integer) matrices, i have separate programs to put them in the reduced form i prefer.

Comment: @Will: which earlier comments?

Comment: Michael, I had asked for help figuring out how to do this task (with ternary forms). It turned out that a subset of my larger program worked very well in this calculator mode. So those requests were no longer relevant, i was able to do it myself, and i deleted them.

Comment: @Remke Kloosterman
In fact it doesn't even have bad reduction at $2$:
the minimal model is $[0, 0, 1, -6, 3]$, with conductor $3^3 7 = 189$,
barely small enough (at most $200$) to be already in Tingley's 
"Antwerp tables" (*Modular Forms in One Variable IV*, **LNM** 476).  Indeed the group of rational points is ${\bf Z} / 3 {\bf Z}$.